# Save extra fields to django model apart from the fields which were present in django form(for the same model)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django model with few fields, In the django forms which is created using that django models. While using the forms.save method I also want to save the extra fields which were not present in Django forms but present in django models.

**models.py**

```
class NewProvisionalEmployeeMail(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (1, ("Permanent")),
    (2, ("Temporary")),
    (3, ("Contractor")),
    (4, ("Intern"))
    )
    PAY_CHOICES = (
    (1, ("Fixed")),
    (2, ("Performance Based")),
    (3, ("Not Assigned")),
    )
    POSITION_CHOICES = ()
    for i, name in enumerate(Position.objects.values_list('position_name')):
        POSITION_CHOICES += ((i, name[0]),)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, null=False, blank=False, unique=False)
    token = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    offer_sent_by = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    position_name = models.IntegerField(choices=POSITION_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pay = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    pay_type = models.IntegerField(choices=PAY_CHOICES, default=3)
    emp_type = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.offer_sent_by) +" to " + str(self.email)


    def clean(self):
        if(NewProvisionalEmployeeMail.objects.filter(email=str(self.email)).exists()):
            NewProvisionalEmployeeMail.objects.filter(email=str(self.email)).delete()

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        return super(NewProvisionalEmployeeMail, self).save(**kwargs)
```

If you see it has following fields : 
`email`, `token`, `offer_sent_by`, `position_name`, `accepted`, `name`, `user_name`, `pay`, `title`, `pay_type`, `emp_type`. 
Now I only want the following fields in my forms : 
`email`, `position_name`, `name`, `user_name`, `pay`, `title`, `pay_type`, `emp_type` and not `token` and `offer_sent_by` whose values will be determined in my views.py using some logic.

**forms.py**

```
class NewProvisionalEmployeeMailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewProvisionalEmployeeMail
        fields = ['email', 'position_name',
        'name', 'user_name', 'pay',
        'title', 'pay_type', 'emp_type',
        ]
```

According to my logic in my views.py the other fields values are generated inside the function, but since to save the model we have to use `formname.save`, here it is `NewProvisionalEmployeeMailForm.save()`. However this will only save the fields which were coming from my template form, how do I also add other left fields while saving using this dunction.

**views.py**

```
def sendoffer(request):
    context = {}
    new_emp_form = NewProvisionalEmployeeMailForm();
    context['form'] = new_emp_form
    hostname = request.get_host() + "/dummyoffer"
    if request.method=='POST':
        new_emp_form = NewProvisionalEmployeeMailForm(request.POST)
        if(new_emp_form.is_valid()):
            token = VALUE COMES FROM LOGIC
            offer_sent_by = VALUE COMES FROM LOGIC
            # I also want to save the fields token, offer_sent_by in my models using this form save method
            new_emp_form.save()

    return render(request, 'mainapp/offer.html',context)
```

As you see `new_emp_form` save method will only save only those fields that are present in the form and not the fields `token` and `offer_sent_by` which is also part of the model. How do save the fields using form.save method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving the form returns an instance of `NewProvisionalEmployeeMail`, so you can simply catch the returned object in a variable and set it's properties afterwards:

```
if(new_emp_form.is_valid()):
    token = VALUE COMES FROM LOGIC
    offer_sent_by = VALUE COMES FROM LOGIC
    new_emp = new_emp_form.save(commit=False)
    new_emp.token = token
    new_emp.offer_sent_by = offer_sent_by
    new_emp.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

for the first time we can change it as following
`new_emp = new_emp_form.save(commit=False)` 
so that i wont save to the database.